# Get the page title for Prestashop 1.7

Tags: variables, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am creating a custom template in Prestashop 1.7 and in the design there is a banner at the top of the page which will include the page title. I can't seem to pull through 1 universal smarty variable that will pull the page title not mattering what page template I am as this will be going in the header.tpl. I have tried with $page.title but that doesn't pull anything through.

Any suggestions will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

In the file for the basic theme in `themes/classic/templates/_partials/head.tpl` they get the title using `{$page.meta.title}`. Not sure it will be acessible from you module, but should.

Comment: Would that not change if I made a more SEO friendly meta title?